# Why am I not getting the output nor an error in web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I am doing an assignment of web scraping on google colab with beautifulsoup and requests. Here I am only scraping the headline of google news. Below is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def beautiful_soup(url):
'''DEFINING THE FUNCTION HERE THAT SENDS A REQUEST AND PRETTIFIES THE TEXT 
INTO SOMETHING THAT IS EASY TO READ'''

request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())

beautiful_soup('https://news.google.com/?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en')

for headlines in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'VDXfz'}):
   print(headlines.text)
```

The problem is that when I run the cell it neither shows the output (list of headlines) nor an error. Please help it is bugging me for 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to display the text from the next `span` element. This could be done as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def beautiful_soup(url):
    '''DEFINING THE FUNCTION HERE THAT SENDS A REQUEST AND PRETTIFIES THE TEXT 
       INTO SOMETHING THAT IS EASY TO READ'''

    request = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
    #print(soup.prettify())
    return soup

soup = beautiful_soup('https://news.google.com/?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en')

for headlines in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'VDXfz'}):
    print(headlines.find_next('span').text)
```

This would give you output starting something like:

```
I Take Back My Comment, Says Ram Madhav After Omar Abdullah’s Dare to Prove Pakistan Charge
Ram Madhav Backpedals On "Instruction From Pak" After Omar Abdullah Dare
National Conference backed PDP to save J&K from uncertainty: Omar Abdullah
On Ram Madhav ‘instruction from Pak’ barb, Omar Abdullah’s stinging reply
Make public reports of horse-trading in govt formation in J-K: Omar Abdullah to Guv
```

---

You could write the headlines to a CSV formatted file using the following approach:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def beautiful_soup(url):
    '''DEFINING THE FUNCTION HERE THAT SENDS A REQUEST AND PRETTIFIES THE TEXT 
       INTO SOMETHING THAT IS EASY TO READ'''

    request = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
    return soup

soup = beautiful_soup('https://news.google.com/?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en')

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Headline'])

    for headlines in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'VDXfz'}):
        headline = headlines.find_next('span').text
        print(headline)
        csv_output.writerow([headline])
```

Currently this just produces a single column called `Headline`

Comment: how do i convert this list into csv?

Comment: What columns would you have? Currently this is just a single column.

Comment: This was tested on my local PC so it was saved in the current folder. I am not able to say where Google colab would save it. I think you need to look at `files.download()`

Comment: I wrote files.download('output.csv') it downloaded the output csv number of times the headline and it did not had any data each Excel file of 0kb

Comment: I got it tested on my local PC got the output!

Answer (score 0):

Executing the following script, you should get the required results. If you used selector, the script would be much cleaner.

However, using `.find_all()`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_headlines(url):
    request = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,"lxml")
    headlines = [item.find_next("span").text for item in soup.find_all("h3")]
    return headlines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = 'https://news.google.com/?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en'
    for titles in get_headlines(link):
        print(titles)
```

To do the same using `.select()`, bring out this change within the script:

```
headlines = [item.text for item in soup.select("h3 > a > span")]
return headlines
```